# No response after executing .sh file and no logs are stored

Tags: linux, networking, redhat, command-line-interface, log-files

I have RHEL 6.5 server. I am trying to upgrade  a software. As per the procedure, i executed the file ./upgrade.sh.

I do not see any response from CLI or GUI. Ideally a upgradation window should pop up. But that is not happening.

Moreover, I am not finding any logs regarding this in /var/log/messages.

There is no restrictions on the permissions.

Comment: We don't know anything about the software you are upgrading and how this `upgrade.sh` script is working. This question can not be answered.

Comment: In other words, add more information about your current setup, the software you tried to update and output in its logs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be addressed to the vendor.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend contacting the support team of the organization who made that software.  Unless you provide more details about the software that you are using, or at least the content of the upgrade.sh script, we probably won't be able to help you any further.